# sed print every 2nd line

Tags: awk, sed

I have below file: main.txt

```
/F/FID/FID/000001/0/20180215//1/2/
/F/FID/FID/000002/0/20180215//1/2/
/F/FID/FID/000003/0/20180215//1/2/
/F/FID/FID/000004/0/20180215//1/2/
/F/FID/FID/000005/0/20180215//1/2/
/F/FID/FID/000006/0/20180215//1/2/
```

I like to use sed to print every two rows into a new file:

file1.txt

```
/F/FID/FID/000001/0/20180215//1/2/
/F/FID/FID/000002/0/20180215//1/2/
```

file2.txt

```
/F/FID/FID/000003/0/20180215//1/2/
/F/FID/FID/000004/0/20180215//1/2/
```

file3.txt

```
/F/FID/FID/000005/0/20180215//1/2/
/F/FID/FID/000006/0/20180215//1/2/
```

Comment: `split` command is better suited here.. see `man split` for details.. if you try that and still have some doubts, you can update the question..

Answer (score 1):

Not easy with `sed`, but

```
awk 'NR%2 {fname = sprintf("file%d.txt", ++n)} {print > fname}' main.txt
```

giving

```
head file*.txt
==> file1.txt <==
/F/FID/FID/000001/0/20180215//1/2/
/F/FID/FID/000002/0/20180215//1/2/

==> file2.txt <==
/F/FID/FID/000003/0/20180215//1/2/
/F/FID/FID/000004/0/20180215//1/2/

==> file3.txt <==
/F/FID/FID/000005/0/20180215//1/2/
/F/FID/FID/000006/0/20180215//1/2/
```

Alternatively,

```
split --lines=2 --numeric-suffixes=1 --suffix-length=1 --additional-suffix='.txt' main.txt 'file'
```

(some of these options may be specific to the GNU version of `split`).